# wrong use of class?

Tags: php, image, file, upload

there occured a suspect problem during my image upload, i´ll show you:

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST">

    File: <input type="file" name="picture" value="" id="picture-field">
    <span class="error" id="file-error"></span>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">

</form>
```

my check.php:

```
require 'ImageChecker.php';

if (!$_FILES)
    echo "exit because no FILES";

$imageChecker = new ImageChecker();

$imageError = "";

if(!$imageChecker->php_error($_FILES['picture']['error'])) {
    $imageError = "php error ocurred!";
    echo $imageError;
```

the class ImageChecker.php:

```
class ImageChecker {

    // function for php-error-check
    public function php_error ($php_error) {
        if ($php_error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }    
    }

    // more functions..
}
```

every time, i upload an image, i get:

```
exit because no FILES
```

and

```
php error ocurred!
```

WHY ? what did i wrong? really need your help, thanks and greetings!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the form tag you need to give 
       enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

this is very important while uploading files

Comment: THANKS, totally forgot, what a fail... :(

Comment: Also need to change line `echo "exit because no FILES";` to `die("exit because no FILES");` because now it generates error and continue execute script.

Comment: Actually, one can also use `exit("exit because no FILES");` or just use `exit;` after `echo` @Narek